# How to retrieve more than one information from the same column?

Tags: mysql

I would like to display all data according to selected information from one column.
In picture below you can see two columns 'WO' and 'Process'.

[Table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nFpW.jpg)

I would like to display Breadboard and Break for specific WO number.

This is the query I've been trying but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
from tblTracker
WHERE WO='3000'
AND Process='Breadboard'
AND Process='Break'
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please remove the link to the image of data and replace it with actual data - ie plain text formatted as vide (indented 4 spaces)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` operator:

```
select *
from tblTracker
where WO = '3000'
and Process in ('Breadboard', 'Break')
```

Answer (score 1):

You process needs to be an OR because both criteria should be met.

You need to enclose the or Statement with parenthesis so that a row is only the displayed when both criteria wo = 3000 and (Process='Breadboard'
OR Process='Break') are true at the same time

```
SELECT *
from tblTracker
WHERE WO='3000'
AND (Process='Breadboard'
OR Process='Break')
```